Does the Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License restrict the second level derivative work?
The Creative Commons Attribution 4.0 International License (CC BY) says:
You are free to:

Share — copy and redistribute the material in any medium or format for any purpose, even commercially.
Adapt — remix, transform, and build upon the material for any purpose, even commercially.

Under the following terms:

Attribution — You must give appropriate credit, provide a link to the license, and indicate if changes were made.
No additional restrictions — You may not apply legal terms or technological measures that legally restrict others from doing anything the license permits.

My reading of this is that it does not have the copyleft restriction that the GPL or any of the Share Alike CC licences such as CC BY-SA.  From my very much non-lawyer reading of this the following actions should be allowed:

Alice creates a work, and publishes it under the CC-BY licence
Bob creates a derivative work, provides appropriate attribution and notice of the very minor changes, and publishes it under the CC0 1.0 which places no restrictions on reuse
Charlie creates a derivative work of Bobs work, removes the attribution and notice of changes and publishes it under a restrictive licence

If this is legal, it would seem to defeat the purpose of the licence.  However I cannot see who is at fault legally in the above situation.  What would be the legal situation here?

[opensource.se] may be a better place to post this question. While it is a legal question, so it's technically on-topic here, you'll find more expertise on the legal issues of open source licenses over there.

Charlie has infringed Alice's copyright by creating a work he knows to be derivative of Alice's work without complying with terms of the license Alice made available to Charlie.
